# Dynamic targets for PedGoTo using several levels

Tags: anylogic

I'm using the pedistrian library in anylogic and want to implement different target locations for different agents in the block PedGoTo. I tried to use setPos(x,y) for TargetLines and setPos(x,y,z) for rectangular areas. Both did not work and the message "Markup element is already initialized and cannot be modified. Please use constructor without arguments, perform setup and finally call initialize() function" made me try another method. I tried to use point(x,y) as a target. This works fine by defining a parameter for both X and Y and overwriting the values during the simulation. Every time a value is changed the next agent has a new target location.

But, the point(x,y) has no z or level parameter. So I assume that it is only working with targets in the same level as the agent release point. There is no way to define another level for the target by using point(x,y).

My Question is: how can I define a target dynamically during runtime in a level which is different from the agent release point level?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Solved it myself by testing my assumption (which was wrong). The problem was that in my flowchart the PedChangeLevel was positioned before PedGoTo, causing that the agent was always going to the stairs first and then searched for x,y in the upper floor. I could solve it by inserting a new pedSelectOutput which conditions which level is the target. Each level also needs to get a PedGoTo as well and then it works fine.

Comment: add it as an answer so others can benefit from it..